# The method getThumbnail is not applicable for the type

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

I tried to use the following snippet to get a thumbnail from my URI of the original image.

```
   Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
           context.getContentResolver(), uri,
           MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
           (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

My URI `uri`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(ki.getEreignisbild());
```

Now, the `getThumbnail` function is red underlined and the error message says

```
The method getThumbnail(ContentResolver, long, int, BitmapFactory.Options) 
in the type MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails is not applicable for the arguments 
(ContentResolver, Uri, int, BitmapFactory.Options)
```

Googled it but not found anything. Any ideas what I can do?

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderEreignis holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_ereignis, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderEreignis((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.enullline), (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.efirstLine), (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eimgv));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolderEreignis) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Ereignis ki = (Ereignis) getItem(position);
    holder.getEreignisname().setText(ki.getEreignisname());
    holder.getEreignisdatum().setText(ki.getEreignisZeit());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(ki.getEreignisbild());



    String imageUri;

 try{

   String path = ki.getEreignisbild();
   Bitmap de = resizeBitmap(path);

   Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
           context.getContentResolver(), uri,
           MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
           (BitmapFactory.Options) null );




  // Drawable drawable = holder.getEreignisbild().setImageDrawable(R.drawable.male);
 //  holder.getEreignisbild().setImageResource(R.drawable.male);

 }
 catch(Exception e){

 }

    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: post the full code..looks like the uri that u are passing in the getThumbnail is of type long and not of URI.

Answer (score -1):

```
getThumbnail(ContentResolver, long, int, BitmapFactory.Options) 
            (ContentResolver, Uri, int, BitmapFactory.Options)
```

See the difference?  You're passing the wrong type for the 2nd argument.

Comment: But the argument I pass is URI like you see it in the code above I added.

Comment: Oh, I understand it must be a long. How can I get the imageid from a URI?

Comment: QUery the media store for the IMAGE_ID for that URI.

Comment: Do you have any link how to do this?